# how to compare two tables in psql using case statement

Tags: psql

I have two table both are same in definition but different in records
one table is having todays date another table is having yesterday's data:--

### TableA-- today's data

> ```
> name,name_code,start_dt,  subname,subname_code,subname_st_date
> abc   Active   12-04-1026 abc1    Active       13-042016
> def   Active   23-03-2016  def987 Active       23-01-2016
> ```

### TableB -- yesterday's data

> ```
> name,name_code,start_dt,  subname,subname_code,subname_st_date
> abc   Inactive 12-04-1026 abc1    Active       13-042016
> def   Active   24-03-2016  def987 Inactive       23-01-2016
> def   Active   24-02-2016  def876 Inactive       23-01-12016
> ```

My requirement is to compare both the table and output should be the difference in records stated as below

For example:---

> ```
> Subname were Cancelled : def987
> New subname added :     def876
> ```

Kindly help.

Comment: You can try this.

SELECT name,subname FROM TableB EXCEPT SELECT name,subname FROM TableA

Comment: i did that... but i want o/p like--Subname were Cancelled : def987

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(
  case 
    when b.subname_code = 'Inactive' 
    then 'Subname were Cancelled :'
    else 'New subname added      :'
  end
  , b.subname) 
from tableb b
left outer join tablea a on a.subname = b.subname
where a.subname_code <> b.subname_code or a.subname_code is null;
```